# Scala configuration in Intellij

Tags: java, scala, ide, intellij-idea

I am trying to run an HelloWorld kind of program for Scala , in Intellij.

My code is:

> package helloscala
>
> object HelloScala {   def main(args: Array[String])   {
>       Console.println("Hello, world!");   } }

I am clueless about the error , that is prompted by the INtellij IDE.

```
 JDK is JDK5
```

Error is:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class
>   file  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
>   Exception in thread "main"

Any input would be great.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are using Java 5? If not then just install a newer JDK.

Comment: Well my current code base is Java 5. I don't want to risk that

Comment: @user1993412 what scala version are you using?

Comment: version is scala 2.9.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Scala 2.10](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads) doesn't support Java 5.

> Software Requirements:
>       The Scala software distribution can be installed on any Unix-like or Windows system. It requires the Java runtime version 1.6 or later.

Comment: He says he is using scala 2.9.2. I think you can remove the `2.10` version from the answer. I think the Software Requirements are valid across all Scala versions.

Comment: @Kaz Sera , I m using Scala 2.9.2

Comment: Yes , it works with JDK 6 only , I think so , if it is feasible to update my code base easily , I would do it. Thanks Guys for the inputs !!!

Comment: I would recommend going all the way to JDK7.

Answer (score 0):

Use JDK 7 + sbt-idea plugin.

[SBT](http://scala-sbt.org) is the preferred build tool

I recommend my project [skeleton](https://github.com/fractal/skeleton) for setting it all up. Intllij + SBT (+eclipse if you so want to)